# TCPClient and TCPListener - NetworkStream - order of messages

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcplistener, networkstream

i have a simple question regarding the order of sent and received messages via TCP classes, I cannot find any 100% answer and my english is not well enough.

If i have following example:

Server:

```
        IPAddress IP = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        int Port = 13000;

        TcpListener Server = new TcpListener(IP, Port);
        TcpClient Client = Server.AcceptTcpClient();
        NetworkStream Stream = Client.GetStream();

        Stream.Write(Buffer1, 0, 4);
        //random time
        Stream.Write(Buffer2, 0, 4);
        //random time
        Stream.Write(Buffer3, 0, 4);
```

and Client:

```
        TCPClient Client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 13000);
        NetworkStream Stream = Client.GetStream();

        Stream.Read(A, 0, 4);
        //random time
        Stream.Read(B, 0, 4);
        //random time
        Stream.Read(C, 0, 4);
```

Is it 100% sure that i will got A = Buffer1, B = Buffer2, C = Buffer3?

Comment: No! You must check the return value of `Stream.Read` to see how many bytes you actually got. TCP is *ordered* (meaning, you are guaranteed to receive bytes in the order you sent them) but also *stream-based* (meaning, the packeting of bytes is not guaranteed). To make it more explicit: TCP does not have messages. If you want messages, you'll have to build them yourself (prefixing them with a length is the most common approach). Consult any tutorial on network code to see how to write a proper receive loop.

Comment: I have already implement this prefixing the first 4B of my message is length of message, so on the other side i read the first 4B and then set NumberOfBytesToRead to that number for another read. I just wanted to confirm the order of messages which you probably answered in first part of you comment :)

Comment: Be careful: you are not guaranteed even to get 4 bytes if you ask for 4 bytes (they could be split across packets), so even reading the length must be done in a loop until you have those 4 bytes. And then you'll need to loop again to get the full message. Getting this wrong is probably the most common error in network programming, and especially devious because this sort of code can work very well by accident or in a test environment, and then fail in production.

Comment: It will be probably my example , i am sending messages < 1kB and everything working fine

Comment: @JeroenMostert  even if the client asks for 4 bytes and the server sends 2 and 2 in different packets, the client will wait until he reads 4 bytes.

Comment: @GeorgeChond Ahh so it will be working for very long messages as well and Jeroen Mostert comment is not true?

Comment: @GeorgeChond: that is explicitly *not* what will happen. Suppose the second packet is delayed or lost? `Stream.Read` will read bytes that are available. It will not wait around for as many bytes to be available as you specify. This is exactly why it returns the number of bytes read in the first place -- otherwise there'd be no need for that.

Comment: For further enlightenment, consult [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873044/q/23985992) in its entirety. This is covered under #4.

Comment: @JeroenMostert no, actually it will just block the thread until all the specified bytes are read, unless you enabled a timeout.

Comment: @GeorgeChond: Regrettably I don't have the time to write up the code and prove this wrong with a practical demonstration. Try it yourself if you want: receive 10,000 bytes on the client end, send one byte on the server end, use an infinite timeout (which is the default anyway). The client will return one byte, not wait until the server is kind enough to send over 9,999 more. To get the behavior you describe, you'd need to wrap the stream in a `BinaryReader`, which does buffer. `Stream` does *not*.

Comment: @JeroenMostert yes you are right, I was confused with the behavior of `BinaryReader`. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: So if i understand correctly guys i have to read first four bytes which means the length of message and then setup condition which is waiting for all bytes mentioned in first 4 bytes, right?

Comment: You could use `BinaryReader` for convenience because it buffers for you -- read the length, then the full message. This way you don't need your own loop. But if you do use `NetworkStream` directly, you must loop, even to read just the first 4 bytes.

Comment: So i will use constructor `BinaryReader(Stream)` and then i can use easily `BinaryReader.Read` instead of `NetworkStream.Read` for reading, right?

Comment: btw i found this for  `BinaryReader.Read (Byte[], Int32, Int32)` : The number of bytes read into buffer. This might be less than the number of bytes requested if that many bytes are not available, or it might be zero if the end of the stream is reached.

Comment: Well this was an interesting over-complicated discussion for such a simple question. :)

Comment: To actually answer your question: TCP keeps the data ordered the way you sent it, so the endpoint will _always_ receive Buffer1, Buffer2 and Buffer3 in that order. _**However**_ as the others have said the data could be split into pieces _**or**_ combined into chunks, so you must design a reliable packet system to read the data correctly (which from my understanding, you already have: the so called _length prefixing_ method).

Comment: Yep as you said, i have 4B prefix which means the length of message. So i have to cycle the reading for receive first four bytes and then another cycle for receive number of bytes mentioned in first 4 bytes, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no guarantee that for each NetworkStream.Write operation it will be correspanding NetworkStream.Read operations that will return the exact data that has been written into to the stream.
Here is a simple example of TcpListner and TcpClient connection:

```
public class NetworkUtils{

    //Client
    TcpClient client = null;
    int port = 40555;
    string serverIpAddress = "127.0.0.1";
    public Mutex mut = new Mutex();
    int byteToExpecting = 0;
    int savedBufferOffset = 0;
    Byte[] saveDataBuffer = new Byte[20000];
    NetworkStream stream;

    public string ServerIpAddress
    {
        get { return serverIpAddress; }
        set { serverIpAddress = value;}
    }

    string lastSentMsg = String.Empty;
    public string LastSentMsg
    {
        get { return lastSentMsg; }
        set { lastSentMsg = value;}
    }

    //Server
    string clientMsg = String.Empty;
    public string ClientMsg
    {
        get { return clientMsg; }
    }
    public void ClearClientMsg()
    {
        clientMsg = String.Empty;
    }

    TcpListener server=null;

    private string errMsg = String.Empty;
    public string ErrMsg
    {
        get { return errMsg; }
        set { errMsg = value;}
    }

    void ConnectToServer()
    {
        client = new TcpClient(serverIpAddress, port);  
    }

    public bool ClientSendMsg(string message)
    {
        try{

            ConnectToServer();

            Byte[] lengthByteArr = IntToByteArr(message.Length);
            client.GetStream().Write(lengthByteArr, 0, lengthByteArr.Length);

            Byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
            client.GetStream().Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            client.GetStream().Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            errMsg = e.Message;
        }

        return errMsg.Length == 0;
    }

    public bool LaunchServer() {
        try {
            IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
            server.Start();
            ListenToClients();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            server.Stop();
        }

        return errMsg.Length == 0;
    }

    void ProcessInformation(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try{

            TcpClient client;
            client = server.EndAcceptTcpClient(result);
            stream = client.GetStream();
            stream.BeginRead(saveDataBuffer, 0, sizeof(Int32), new AsyncCallback(callbackGetHeadrer), null);
            ListenToClients ();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            errMsg = e.Message;
            server.Stop();
        }
    }

    void callbackGetHeadrer (IAsyncResult asyncResult) { 
        int lenToRead = stream.EndRead(asyncResult);

        savedBufferOffset = 0;
        byteToExpecting = ByteArrToInt (saveDataBuffer);
        saveDataBuffer = new byte[byteToExpecting];
        stream.BeginRead (saveDataBuffer, 0, byteToExpecting, callback, null);
    }

    void callback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) { 

        int lenToRead = stream.EndRead(asyncResult);

        byteToExpecting -= lenToRead;
        savedBufferOffset += lenToRead;

        /*No one is gurentee that the 'lenToRead' will be correspanding to NetworkStream.Write execution order.
        We need to keep read from the stream until we will get waht we are expecting accrding 'byteToExpecting'
        So here we are keep calling 'stream.BeginRead'.*/
        if (byteToExpecting > 0) {
            stream.BeginRead (saveDataBuffer, savedBufferOffset, byteToExpecting, callback, null);
        } 
        else{
            mut.WaitOne();
            clientMsg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(saveDataBuffer,0, saveDataBuffer.Length);
            mut.ReleaseMutex();

            savedBufferOffset = 0;
            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
    }

    bool ListenToClients()
    {
        try{
            server.BeginAcceptTcpClient( new AsyncCallback( ProcessInformation), server);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            errMsg = e.Message;
            server.Stop();
        }

        return errMsg.Length == 0;
    }

    public Byte[] IntToByteArr(Int32 intValue)
    {
        byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(intValue);

        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            Array.Reverse(intBytes);
        return intBytes;
    }

    public Int32 ByteArrToInt(Byte[] intByteArr)
    {
        Int32 Int32_NUM_OF_BYTES = 4;
        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Int32_NUM_OF_BYTES];

        for (int i = 0; i < Int32_NUM_OF_BYTES; ++i)
            buffer [i] = intByteArr [i];

        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            Array.Reverse (buffer);

        return BitConverter.ToInt32 (buffer, 0);
    }
}
```

Note that 'callbackGetHeadrer ' responsible of getting the data size that we will be expecting to receive. later, we are keep reading from the stream using 'stream.BeginRead' until we will get what we are expecting, regarding the sequence of the 'stream.Write' operation.

Comment: Yep you are right, I used something similiard. Btw from .NET 4.5 you can use async await. NetworkStream has new methods as `.ReadAsync` and `.WriteAsync` which are much more user friendly than old `.BeginRead`